# programaticly assign objects to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that I am adding objects to. I would like to control the number of objects that are added to the array using a number.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCountries; i++) {
    chartArray[i] = obj[i];
}
```

I am trying to get this:

```
    chartArray[0] = obj0;
    chartArray[1] = obj1;
    chartArray[2] = obj2;
    chartArray[3] = obj3;
    chartArray[4] = obj4;
    chartArray[5] = obj5;
```

Comment: how are obj1-5 assigned?

Comment: `chartArray[i] = window.["obj " + i];` ?

Comment: `if (chartArray.length > 5) break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `obj` variables are available at window scope:

```
for (var i=0; i<numberOfCountries; i++) {
    chartArray[i] = window["obj"+i];
}
```

Comment: yes, obj is available at window scope, thanks, this is just was I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

May be you want this?

```
for (var i=0; i<numberOfCountries; i++) {
    chartArray.push(this["obj"+i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the index of for loop is 0:

You have this code:

```
chartArray[0] = obj[0];
```

in this code you try to push an elemento of an array named "obj" with index 0 to your chartArray in index 0.

to do what you want you must resolve the name of the object by adding a sequential number to the word "obj" to do so you can use eval().

Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCountries; i++) {
   //for debug uncomment nexr line 
   //console.log("name:","obj"+i,"eval:",eval("obj"+i));
   if(typeof eval("obj"+i) !== "undefined") return chartArray.push(eval("obj"+i));
}
```

if object named "obj"+i isn't defined the loop continue to next "Countrie" whitout add to your array.

bye.

Answer (score 0):

I really get the feeling you are asking the wrong question (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The objects you refer to should be in an array in the first place

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
var char = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    char.push(obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: `obj` is not an array, as per the code under *I am trying to get this..*

Comment: Well I'm sorry, when i saw chartArray[i] = obj[i]; i though obj[i] was working and that he had an error somewhere else while assigning his values.